# How can I get a drive list from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003, drive-mapping

I'm trying to get a list of all my mapped drives for a system upgrade and would like to get this info via a batch file.  How can I do this?

For Bonus points:
How can I script the mapping of these drives on the new server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of current mappings will be returned by

```
net use
```

The transfer would work like this (for the fun<sup>1</sup> of it, lets do that in batch script instead of VBScript):

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set letter=.
set uncpath=.
set colon=.

for /f "delims=" %%l in ('net use') do @(
  for /f "tokens=2" %%t in ("%%l") do @set letter=%%t
  for /f "tokens=3" %%t in ("%%l") do @set uncpath=%%t

  set colon=!letter:~1,1!

  if "!colon!" EQU ":" (
    echo if exist !letter! net use !letter! /delete
    echo net use !letter! !uncpath! /persistent:yes
  )
)

endlocal
```

output goes something like this:

```
if exist M: net use M: /delete
net use M: \\someserver\someshare /persistent:yes
if exist N: net use N: /delete
net use N: \\otherserver\othershare /persistent:yes
```

Just store that in a batch file and you are good to go.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, "fun" is not the right word here. ;-)

Comment: Wow! are you a coding android sent from the future to save/destroy us all? :)

Comment: No. This assumption is wrong on at least one account. ;-) In fact I've never done anything like this in a batch script before, but hey - it seems to work. :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm with Joel here....you are out to destroy us all....man!, that dos environment really has some legs.

Comment: BTW: Tamalak is your avatar reversed by accident?  or are you against hackers?

Comment: @Keng: It's not much uglier than Perl, I would say (even though less capable). But that's just an opinion. ;-) I would not say my avatar is reversed. The glider is stable in any direction, so I don't think orientation matters here.

Answer (score 2):

To list the mapped drives

```
Net Use
```

To map a new drive

```
Net Use G: \\Server\Path
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using vbscript

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives

For Each objDrive in colDrives
    Wscript.Echo "Drive letter: " & objDrive.DriveLetter
Next
```

And you can map network drives with

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "G:", "\\Server\Path"
```

Comment: Your first script would list all the drives on the PC, including any local drive, not just the mapped network drives.

Comment: You could check objDrive.DriveType to ensure it is a network drive (DriveType=3).